# lazy loading shows blank page in safari and firefox until fully loaded

Tags: javascript, firefox, safari, lazy-loading

I have a page with a lot of medical videos that are being fed into the site through javascript that is causing the website to really slow down. I'm using blazy.js to add lazy loading to the videos and it's working in chrome but in safari and firefox, it just shows a blank page until everything is fully loaded.

**Edit:1**
This is how the video is loaded

```
          <div id="A_b9c76c75" ></div>
          <script type="text/javascript" 
          src="https://viewmedica.com/js/vm.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" >client = "1202";
          openthis = "A_b9c76c75";
          width = 720;
          vm_open()</script>
```

**End of Edit 1**

I tried switching over to lazyload.js version 8 (version 10 is not working with safari and firefox) but the same thing is happening.

**lazyload.js version:**

```
<!--lazy loading-->
<script>
    (function(w, d){
        var b = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        var s = d.createElement("script"); s.async = true;
        var v = !("IntersectionObserver" in w) ? "8.11.0" : "10.11.1";
        s.src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vanilla-lazyload/" + v + "/lazyload.min.js";
        w.lazyLoadOptions = {}; // Your options here. See "recipes" for more information about async.
        b.appendChild(s);
    }(window, document));
</script>

<script>
    var myLazyLoad = new LazyLoad({
        elements_selector: ".lazy"
    });
</script>
```

and then I add the "lazy" class to all of iframe.

**blazy.js version:**

added this cdn:

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/blazy@1.8.2/blazy.min.js

and then added the class "b-lazy" to all of the iframes.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are adding the videos to your html but you can use the preload attribute for video elements. 
Linked here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-preload

In addition, you can also set the poster attribute to add a placeholder while the video loads.

```
<video preload="auto" poster="my-placeholder.jpg">
  <source src="my-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: I edited my post above on how the video is loaded and I did not know about the preloader so this is very interesting but they sadly do not allow the use of video element to load the videos because their videos need their player to play and also to prevent people from downloading their videos.